# Latex BibTex doesnt find database entry

Tags: latex, bibtex

For my thesis I used the following latex template. But even in the template, the library does not work properly with me.

https://github.com/MichaelGrupp/TTT

The following message appiers after using the BibTeX Command:

> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: TUM_Thesis_Template.aux The style file: plain.bst A
>   level-1 auxiliary file: titlepage.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   titlepage_inside.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   content/EidesstattlicheErklaerung.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   content/Abstract.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   content/Acknowledgements.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   content/ExampleChapterOne.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
>   content/ExampleChapterTwo.aux I couldn't open database file
>   bib/references.bib.bib ---line 29 of file TUM_Thesis_Template.aux :
>   \bibdata{bib/references.bib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this
>   command A level-1 auxiliary file: content/AppendixExample.aux I found
>   no database files---while reading file TUM_Thesis_Template.aux
>   Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "hartley2004" (There were
>   2 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

I have no idea how to react on this error message. My notebook is a corporate notebook and the versions of Miktex and Texmaker are the only ones released.

Answer (score 6):

The error message contains "I couldn't open database file bib/references.bib.bib".

You need to change

`\bibliography{bib/references.bib}`

to

`\bibliography{bib/references}`

since it will add on the ".bib" extension automatically.

Source: [Documentation for \bibliography](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#index-_005cbibliography)